# How to add directus sdk to android studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, directus

Could someone please help me in adding the directus sdk into android studio as i am a bit new to this. Thanks!

I have tried- **implementation 'io.directus:directus-sdk:1.1.1'**, in build.gradle but this doesn't seem to work, am i missing something?

Directus SDK Link:-
https://github.com/directus/sdk-java

Edit

**Code Placement**

app -> build.gradle

Dependencies
{
 . 
 .
 implementation 'io.directus:directus-sdk:1.1.1'
}

**Error**: Failed to resolve: io.directus:directus-sdk:1.1.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

**Edit 2:**
Maven version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin..
Java version: 13.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

javac 11.0.4

JDK- 13.0.2

Comment: can you post the error what error are you getting?

Comment: @haresh added it, please have a look! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Document is not up-to the mark

Do below steps

1. Download repo and go to path in CMD
2. Then hit `mvn install` & `mvn deploy` consecutively. (***Make sure selected Compiler provided in environment should be JDK not JRE*** otherwise you may face build failure)
3. After that go to Android Studio and Perform `Try again/Sync`

It should build successfully without any error.

Comment: Thanks for your response but i get 4 errors, one of which is (** Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.4:jar (attach-javadocs) on project directus-sdk: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:**). Compiler is set to JDK, let me know if more information is to be provided, Thank!

Comment: Can you share folder path where you downloaded repo and path inside which you hit mvn install?

Comment: "C:\Users\xyz\Downloads\sdk-java-master" is where i downloaded and ran cmd, also i tried 'mvn clean install -X' and now i am getting ( **Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project directus-sdk:** ) and ( **/C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/sdk-java-master/src/main/java/io/directus/client/Pair.java:[16,18] package javax.annotation does not exist** )

Comment: Upgrade maven to 3.6.3. latest. If you still face issues then raise this issue on https://github.com/directus/sdk-java/issues/new

Comment: Ohh ok,Yup its the latest version. Thanks for your support.

Comment: So i added few lines in pom.xml (will add the code here once i get it to work) and got it to install, but in mvn deploy i get this error ( **Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project directus-sdk: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter** ), any idea on this? which directory should i specify?

Answer (score 1):

So i got it to work

1. appended this to dependency in pom.xml

   `<dependency>
       <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.2</version>
       </dependency>`
2. Changed javadoc version to the latest version (3.1.1 as of now).
3. Used mavenlocal() in android studio.